# How can I get PyRun_SimpleString(s) output string from Object-C codes？

Tags: python, xcode

How can I get PyRun_SimpleString(s) output string from Object-C codes？
When I run below codes, return code is 0. But I can see output logs only in lldb in Xcode. Is there any way to get the result str to char* or NSString*?

```objectivec
Py_Initialize();
NSString* commandStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hasattr(list, \"%@\")", @"append"];
int ret = PyRun_SimpleString([commandStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); NSLog(@"");
```

Comment: Py_Initialize();
            NSString* commandStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hasattr(list, \"%@\")", @"append"];
            int ret = PyRun_SimpleString([commandStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            NSLog(@"");

Comment: Please edit your question, thank you.